# Select worksheet in excel with xlwt

Tags: python, xlwt

How do I select a worksheet in excel with xlwt? I have tried searching all over and cannot find an answer, all I can find is a bunch of post's on how to copy.

Answer (score 0):

`xlwt` is for writing files, `xlrd` for reading. So you would usually either read a file with `xlrd` and then copy it or create a completely new one with `xlwt`.

It sounds like you're looking for the second solution:

```
wb_out = xlwt.Workbook() # create a new workbook
ws_out = wb_out.add_sheet(sheet_name) # create a new sheet and save the reference

# write some daqa
ws_out.write(row, col, value)

# save the new file
wb_out.save('output.xls')
```

For an existing workbook (for example which was opened with `open_workbook` you can access the sheets either by name or index:

```
sh = wb_out.sheet_by_name("mysheet")
sh = wb_out.sheet_by_index(0)
```

To copy and modify a file you can use `xlutils`: [example here](https://xlutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/copy.html)

Comment: Didn't seem to work. I am getting "NameError: name 'wb_out' is not defined"

Comment: That is just an example. You probably named your workbook differently? Substitute it with a reference to your Workbook object.

Comment: I didn't use "mysheet" I used the name of the worksheet itself.